# Unable to create the log file after click 'Add to cart' button

Tags: magento

I need to create a log file after click the 'Add to cart' button. But my code is not creating a log file when i click the 'Add to cart' button please help. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
config.xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Featured_Attribute>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Featured_Attribute>
      </modules>
      <global>      

        <helpers>
          <attribute>
            <class>Featured_Attribute_Helper</class>
          </attribute>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <attribute>
            <class>Featured_Attribute_Block</class>
          </attribute>
        </blocks>
        <models>
          <attribute>
            <class>Featured_Attribute_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>attribute_mysql4</resourceModel>
          </attribute>
          <attribute_mysql4>
            <class>Featured_Attribute_Model_Mysql4</class>
          </attribute_mysql4>
            <catalog_resource>
                  <rewrite>
                      <product_collection>Featured_Attribute_Model_Resource_Product_Collection</product_collection>
                  </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>



            <events>
                <add_to_cart_after>
                    <observers>
                            <add_to_cart_after>
                                    <class>attribute/observer</class>
                                    <method>hookToAddToCartAfter</method>
                            </add_to_cart_after>
                    </observers>
                </add_to_cart_after>
            </events>
            <template>
                <email>
                    <custom_order_tpl module="Featured_Attribute">
                        <label>Status Mail Invoice</label>
                        <file>sendemail_processing.html</file>
                        <type>html</type>
                    </custom_order_tpl>
                </email>
            </template>



            <resources>
          <attribute_setup>
            <setup>
              <module>Featured_Attribute</module>
                      <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
              <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
          </attribute_setup>
          <attribute_write>
            <connection>
              <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
          </attribute_write>
          <attribute_read>
            <connection>
              <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
          </attribute_read>
        </resources>
      </global>
      <admin>
        <routers>
          <attribute>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
              <module>Featured_Attribute</module>
              <frontName>attribute</frontName>
            </args>
          </attribute>
        </routers>
      </admin>

      <!-- This is for frontend process -->
      <frontend>
            <routers>
                <attribute>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Featured_Attribute</module>
                        <frontName>attributefront</frontName>
                    </args>
                </attribute>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <attribute>
                        <file>attributefront.xml</file>
                    </attribute>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
    </config>

    Observer.php
    <?php
    class Featured_Attribute_Model_Observer
    {
        public function hookToAddToCartAfter($observer) 
        {
                //Hooking to our own event
            //$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getParams();
                // do something with product
            Mage::log("Product is added to cart.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is my config.xml and Observer.php files

Answer (score 0):

There is no event called "add_to_cart_after" in standard magento. Instead of this you need to use "checkout_cart_product_add_after" or "checkout_cart_add_product_complete". Here is the new part of your config:

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <add_to_cart_after>
                <class>attribute/observer</class>
                <method>hookToAddToCartAfter</method>
            </add_to_cart_after>
        </observers>
     </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

Also you should know that Mage::log("Product is added to cart."); will work only if developer mode is enabled. In the other way you need to use

```
Mage::log("Product is added to cart.", null, 'system.log', true);
```